Grouping Rows of Data to Generate analytical
I am working with a data set of NHS attendance data (a snippet of the columns and rows are included). The data continues all the way until the final hour of Sunday. I have successfully cleaned the data and I am now trying to first find ‘the most common reason for attendance on weekends VS weekdays’. I am also later going to find ‘the most common hour for attendance across the whole week’ and hopefully ‘most common reason for attendance between 8am and (including) 7pm, and 8pm-7am’.
I have included the code I managed to make so far, but I am trying to use loops, basic functions and conditional statements to generate the code. I would appreciate any advice on what I have so far, and if there is a better way to approach what I’m doing in order to make the next analysis questions easier, as I currently don't fully understand what I am doing. I don’t really know how to approach any of the questions to begin with, so would be grateful for any basic guidance. I also wondered if maybe there was a way to make a function to always exclude unknown values marked as ‘Undisclosed’ as they are non-integers? I have also read a bit about groupby using Pandas and wondered if that could be applicable?
#Analytical Insight 1: Most Common Reason for Attendance on Weekdays vs Weekends
weekend_data = {} #creating empty dictionary to store the data

for index, row in NHSdata.iterrows():
  if row['Weekday'] == 'Saturday' or row['Weekday'] == 'Sunday':
    for reason in ['Road traffic accident', 'Assualt', 'Deliberate self-harm', 'Sports injury', 'Not known']: #iterating through columns
      if row[reason] != 'Undisclosed':
        weekend_data[reason] = weekend_data.get(reason, 0) + int(row[reason]) #converts row[reason] to integer

weekend_df = pd.DataFrame([weekend_data])
print("Weekend Data:")
print(weekend_df)

Portion of Dataset

Welcome to SO. Can you please provide your data in a reproducible format? A photo of the data is very difficult for people to use. Read this for more help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is meant for specific questions, not broad questions like this, and certainly not multiple at a time. (For reference, see How to ask a good question.) Instead, it seems like you'd be better served by doing a Pandas tutorial. (cont'd...)

On the official site, you can check out Getting started tutorials, 10 minutes to pandas, Community tutorials, and the complete User Guide

But if it helps get you pointed in the right direction, you should consider "Undisclosed" as missing, e.g. if you're loading from CSV, specify na_values='Undisclosed', and it'll be converted to NaN. And if you want to use integers instead of floats (though it probably doesn't matter), specify 'Int64' as the dtype.

I used the fake data (df) below to compute the total number of injuries happening during the week-ends for each type of injury:

df = df.replace("Undisclosed", 0)  # replace the undisclosed value by 0
df = df[df["Weekday"].isin(["Saturday", "Sunday"])]  # filter on weekends
res = df.sum(axis=0)[2:]  # get the sum per column
print(res)

RoadTrafficAccident    213
Assault                252
DeliberateSelfHarm     215
SportsInjury           115
NotKnown               415

